# How do environment variables work for a login shell?

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables

I am writing my own shell and I have a bit of confusion about environment variables. If you start any process logged into the user, it will have access to a few “standard environment variables” such as PATH. According to my research, the login shell sets these “standard environment variables”. So logically, according to what I know about environment variables, all processes owned by the user should be child-processes of the login shell. So my question is, are all processes owned by the user indeed child-processes of the login shell, or does the login shell store environment variables in a special way so that the processes owned by the user can access them?

Comment: `are all processes in the userspace indeed child-processes of the login shell` For one you can have more than one login shell with even just one user. Let alone "login login shells" that started directly from a tty or ssh login, any shell runs from them or from the system manager (e.g. systemd) *can be* a login shell. AFAIK the only thing "special" about it is just what extra files it will source. (You can probably write a shell that does not differentiate whether it is "login or not".)

Comment: Also env var is not something that is specific to shells. Every process has its own env vars. The env vars can either be set by the process itself or inherited from its parent, and the process does not *have to* inherit all env vars either, AFAIK. (Think about `env`.)

Comment: `are all processes in the userspace indeed child-processes of the login shell` .. no!  "userspace" has nothing to do with the user and you appear to be using it that way.  This term means "not in the kernel".  systemd (or init) run in "userspace" and are what run the login shell (along with everything else).  try the `pstree` command and `tree /proc` command.  Anything you see on this list is running in userspace.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Oops. I'll edit the question, so there is no more confusion.

Comment: @TomYan But where does it inherit variables like PATH from? Unless you are suggesting the process is creating its own PATH variable, which I am pretty sure is not the case for many processes.

Comment: @TomYan Also, if your first comment is true, what is the purpose of a login shell?

Comment: Most often `PATH` in a shell is from `/etc/profile` (and often the additional script files in `/etc/profile.d/` that get chain-sourced by `/etc/profile`). But really it's just a convention. A process / shell can do whatever it likes in terms of this, like make use of a hard-coded value, (not) inherit the value from its parent process (e.g. a shell), or read from other arbitrary files (e.g. the other convention `/etc/environment` and friends).

Comment: While there might be other significance I'm not aware of, the only purpose as far as I can see is to determine whether certain files should be sourced.

Comment: I think the real misunderstanding you have is that you seem to think an arbitrary process needs to "ask" a parent or a "login shell" every time it needs the value of an env var. But env var does not work like that at all. Every process has its own "copy" of env vars. For example you change `PATH` in one shell, the `PATH` in other shells / processes that have *already been started* remain the same. Also a process does not have to be started from a shell (login or not). I think you might want to check out `fork` and/or `execve` btw, although I'm no expert of them myself at all.

Comment: @TomYan I know that child processes just inherit the parent processes' environment variables and don't need to ask for them. My only confusion is _from where_ do the processes owned by the user get the same PATH variable that the login shell set?